# Why is my game showing desktop CSS when I test it on my phone?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I'm trying to make [my game](http://playclassicsnake.com/play) responsive, making certain elements hide or rearrange at screen size breakpoints, and have been testing it out by messing with the size of my browser window. The problem is that when I test it out on my phone, everything is in desktop mode, i.e. none of my media queries seem to have been applied. Any idea why?

CSS:

```
body { background: #000; color: #FFF;}
a.navbar-brand { font-size: 20px; }
h3 { font-size: 17px; }
p, li, td, a.btn-lg { font-size: 12px; }
h1:hover, h3:hover, p:hover, li:hover, td:hover { color: #19FF19; transition: color 0.5s; }
form[name="speedform"] table, form[name="speedform"] table td { border: 0; }
#snake-board-holder { width: 100%; border: 1px solid #FFF; background: url('/Content/images/grid.png'); background-size: cover; margin-top: 5%;}
#speed-form tr > td { border: 0; }
#the-modal { color: #000; }
    .modal-footer { margin-top: 0; }
    .modal-body > p { margin-bottom: 0; }
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    #snake-cp-holder table tr > td:last-of-type { text-align: left; }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .game-column { margin-bottom: 5%; } 
 a.navbar-brand { font-size: 12px; }
 h3 { font-size: 18px; }
 thead h3 { text-align: center; }
 p, li, td, a.btn-lg { font-size: 14px; }
 .table-responsive { border: 0; }
 .table-responsive > .table { background: none; border: 0; } /* Override Bootstrap's giving the tables a white background on mobile devices */
 /*#snake-board-holder > svg { background: url(/Content/images/arrows-sphere.png); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; opacity: 0.2; transition: opacity 1s ease;  }*/
}
@media (max-width: 479px)
{
    /* Rearrange/subtract elements for small mobile devices */
    .table-responsive { overflow-x: hidden; }
    .hide-under-480px { display: none;}
    #snake-cp-holder table tr > td:last-of-type { text-align: center; }
    #snake-scores-holder a.btn { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    #snake-scores-holder a.btn + a.btn { margin-top: 10px; }
}
```

Btw my phone is a Nokia Lumia, Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have meta viewport in the head tag?
Can you confirm that your phone loads the css that you provided?

Maybe I didn't fully get it from your question, but when you say test it on your phone do you mean on the actual phone or do oyu pick your phone from a device list in google dev tools, because if it is the second one than you need to reload the page for each size for accurate element representation on the page.